# Installing StarMade on the Surface Pro

Tags: starmade

Here is StarMade:
http://star-made.org/

and here is where I found my graphics driver update:
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=38826

Im running Java (Version 7 Update 25).

Using the Intel HD Graphics 4000 Card, driver version 9.17.10.3062 (which windows tells me is the newest)

It looks like it supports up to OpenGL v4: http://www.intel.com/support/graphics/sb/CS-033757.htm

I'm having trouble running StarMade on the Surface pro. When I run it I get an error saying a JVM Crash has been detected, and that I should update my Intel graphics drivers (which I've since done). Then when I run the game it crashes without throwing an error.

I've also checked the forums with no help, although it seems to be a known issue. (im also not going to uninstall my graphics driver): http://star-made.org/content/launcher-will-not-launch-game

Has anyone been able to run StarMade on the surface pro?

Comment: Is there a reason you deleted your answer?

Comment: Yes, I was wrong, It appears that my graphics card does support OpenGL 2.1:  http://www.intel.com/support/graphics/sb/CS-033757.htm